# Spring RestTemplate BufferingClientHttpRequestWrapper bug?

Tags: java, resttemplate

I'm reading the source code of class BufferingClientHttpRequestWrapper:

```
final class BufferingClientHttpRequestWrapper extends AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest {

private final ClientHttpRequest request;


BufferingClientHttpRequestWrapper(ClientHttpRequest request) {
    Assert.notNull(request, "'request' must not be null");
    this.request = request;
}


public HttpMethod getMethod() {
    return this.request.getMethod();
}

public URI getURI() {
    return this.request.getURI();
}

@Override
protected ClientHttpResponse executeInternal(HttpHeaders headers, byte[] bufferedOutput) throws IOException {
    OutputStream body = this.request.getBody();
    this.request.getHeaders().putAll(headers);
    FileCopyUtils.copy(bufferedOutput, body);
    ClientHttpResponse response = this.request.execute();
    return new BufferingClientHttpResponseWrapper(response);
}

}
```

In the overrided method **executeInternal**,

```
OutputStream body = this.request.getBody();
this.request.getHeaders().putAll(headers);
FileCopyUtils.copy(bufferedOutput, body);
ClientHttpResponse response = this.request.execute();
```

I noticed that **this.request.getBody()** comes before **this.request.getHeaders().putAll(headers)**, which may be a bug causing the passed in **headers** never be written. Say, if the wrapped request is an instance of **SimpleStreamingClientHttpRequest**, the related source code of **SimpleStreamingClientHttpRequest** is as folows:

```
@Override
protected OutputStream getBodyInternal(HttpHeaders headers) throws IOException {
    if (this.body == null) {
        int contentLength = (int) headers.getContentLength();
        if (contentLength >= 0 && !olderThanFroyo) {
            this.connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(contentLength);
        } else {
            this.connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(this.chunkSize);
        }
        writeHeaders(headers);
        this.connection.connect();
        this.body = this.connection.getOutputStream();
    }
    return new NonClosingOutputStream(this.body);
}

@Override
protected ClientHttpResponse executeInternal(HttpHeaders headers) throws IOException {
    try {
        if (this.body != null) {
            this.body.close();
        } else {
            writeHeaders(headers);
            this.connection.connect();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // ignore
    }
    return new SimpleClientHttpResponse(this.connection);
}
```

From above code snippet, We can tell that once getBody() is called(which calls getBodyInternal()), the headers was written to the **connection**(HttpUrlConnection) and calling execute()(which calls executeInternal()) will **NOT** write the headers.(cos **this.body** will not be null). In this case, let's return to **BufferingClientHttpRequestWrapper**'s implementation:

```
OutputStream body = this.request.getBody();
this.request.getHeaders().putAll(headers);
FileCopyUtils.copy(bufferedOutput, body);
ClientHttpResponse response = this.request.execute();
```

The first line will cause the old headers be written, and the second line trying to put new  headers entries is in vain(cos the fouth line will never write headers, as explained above).

Is this a BUG or am I wrong? (Anyway, I'll try it out by practice when I'm in no hurry...)